# Using pandas with ArcPy, ArcGIS Pro, ArcGIS Portal and Survey123

Tags: arcpy, arcgis-pro, pandas, arcgis-portal, arcgis-survey123

My organization has a Python script that essentially logs into our organization’s Portal account, reads the data submitted on a corresponding Survey123 form, then creates two output tables summarizing the data collected. It first takes the contents of the survey123 feature layer and dumps them unformatted into a raw data table. This step still completes without error. The script then takes that data and does some complicated formatting of the records to combine them together, reformat dates, make new columns etc. in a Python dataframe inside the script and saves it to the second excel file. When the script fails it is during this process, because the error message pops up and this data table is left empty.

We have been using this script for years without much issue, but recently this script has completely stopped working after my colleagues and I upgraded ArcGIS Pro to version 3.1.

When we go to run the script, we get the following error:

> ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: 'None’

After much discussion internally, we believe that the error is coming from an outdated Pandas function. We believe we have identified where two chunks of code that are potentially outdated:

[image]

```
#Provenience table processing
first = ['projectid', 'shovel_test_name', ]
new_data['Provenience'] = new_data[first].apply(lambda row: '-'.join(row.values.astype(str)), axis=1)
#allcol = new_data.applymap(str)
new_data.fillna("")
```

[image]

```
#concatenates the data into a single df
frames = [strat1,strat2,strat3,strat4,strat5]
result = pd.concat(frames, sort = True)
#print (result)
#removes empty stratums
trimmed = result[result.soil_texture != 'None']
```

This is our best guess at finding the error location(s), but it is definitely possible that we are wrong about that. This Python debugging effort is unfortunately beyond the skill level any of us have using Python.

Comment: What version of Python are you using? Python has been upgraded to version 3.9.16. for ArcGIS Pro 3.1 https://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/latest/get-started/whats-new-in-arcgis-pro.htm#ESRI_SECTION1_AB3F982B6A174B74AFF373A90D77CA20